# Use SSIS C# script to run SQL plus SQL string

Tags: c#, ssis, sqlplus, ssis-2008, script-task

I am attempting to use a script task (C#) within SSIS (SQL Server 2008 BIDS) and am having trouble sending the actual SQL string to SQL plus. I can get it to take my username and password, but cannot seem to get it to take a SQL string from the C# script. I cannot have the SQL be in a .sql file, and need to be able to send the SQL as a string from within the C# script - any ideas?

Here is my code (sql string commented out):

```
public void Main()

    {
        ProcessStartInfo processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        //string SQLstring = UPDATE table SET field1 = 'xxx' WHERE id2 = 'yyyy'
        processInfo.FileName = "sqlplus.exe";
        processInfo.Arguments = "user/pass@database";
        Process process = Process.Start(processInfo);
    }
```

How can I include the SQL string and send it to SQL plus to execute? Also, will SSIS known when the script is done running and not move to the next task until complete?

Thank you all for your assistance

Comment: Wouldn't your arguments need to include your `SQLstring` variable?

Comment: Thanks, I have tried (unsuccessfully) using the variable in the arguments sections, however, am not getting the syntax correct - for that matter, it is not even giving me an error message (a cmd window pops up quickly then disappears)

If I attempt to add the variable name within the " marks, it does not recognize the variable, and if I include on the outside, nothing happens (..." + sqlString;)

Comment: And you know for *certain* that if you were at the command line and typed `sqlplus.exe user/pass@database "update table set field1='xxx' where id2='yyyy'"` would work. Also if you want someone to see your response @ theirName and they'll get a notification flag. Otherwise, it's hit or miss on whether someone clicks back into a question

Comment: @billinkc -sorry about that. Yes, the SQL string will work if I was to go through the command prompt. Currently, if I remove the SQLstring variable, it correctly passes through the user name and password and gets me to the SQL prompt. If I then type in the SQL there and run it, it works great. I would just like the SQL to be sent to the command window from the C# code. A test I have tried is to see if I can get text to appear at the SQL prompt (after login) but no luck yet, I do not even get an error message. I see a quick screen flash, and then it goes back to SSIS and the task is green

Comment: Why can't your sql be in a .sql file? If I were restricted from storing files on the SSIS server, I'd try to create a file in memory in the script task with the sql query, and just send that. As long as you don't save the file locally to the SSIS box you should be ok, right?

Comment: Since you have the correct command line string, just run it in an execute process task. Explanations like "tried unsuccessfully", "attempting" and "having trouble" don't give any clues to your actual issue. It seems to me that still have some analysis to complete